# Is "Negro" an offensive word, or do some people just take offense to it, and why?

Tags: offensive-language

I was not born in the US, so let me clarify why I'm asking such question:

In Portuguese, the word "Negro" is the correct term when referring to the race, where calling somebody "Black", the color, would be considered offensive most of the time.

So is "Negro" in America a bad, offensive word, or is it the right term when referring to the race?

Comment: A prophecy: as most controversial topics, this one is going to raise to the tops. See also [relevant topics of ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5800/woman-is-the-n-word-of-the-world).

Comment: I don't see any reason to vote up this question because it has nothing to do with the the fruitful scope that ELL should follow. It is worth noting that this scope is learning English grammar. Here I don't see any grammatical question.

Comment: @Carlo_R. "English Language Learners". I'm asking a purely educational question, and if you read it, you can see why. It is important, and it is the solely purpose of this site to educate people learning the English language. I apologize if this question is offensive to anyone, but the reason I ask is so I have an explanation and learn the correct terminology.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Vocabulary is surely as important to learning a language as grammar is.

Comment: @Mark, sorry, I voted up your instructive answer, but I'm uncomfortable with guisasso's question, probably because the social implications of using that word.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I agree with your discomfort, but here at ELL I think that this is an important topic at least for speakers in the US. It would be a shame if a poor word choice caused a problem for someone.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Specially since it is the correct word in a country, but apparently controversial/wrong in another. Hence  this question.

Comment: I'm not offended by this question, but are you genuinely uncertain as to whether the word is regarded as offensive, or are you merely puzzled by its designation thus, and wanting to know why it's regarded as offensive?

Comment: This question is fine. It is on topic and can be useful for other. I don't see any reason why it should be closed. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the controversy here. The word "Negro" is *significantly* less offensive than its fraught sibling, the so-termed "N-word". I mean, it shouldn't be casually tossed around, but in my experience, it isn't considered a slur or demeaning so much as simply archaic.

Comment: This may be slightly o.t. but I think it should also be ethnicity not race

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Negro** is currently considered somewhat offensive in the United States, and it's not advisable to use it if you are first learning the language.

I say "somewhat" because there are circumstances where it is still used, but those circumstances are historically and socially complex, and even Americans still struggle with those circumstances.

It's best to either look for a more neutral term - *black* or *African-American* are currently* better choices - or to avoid the reference to race except where necessary. It's also a good idea to take the cue from the person you are describing - what word, if any, would they be comfortable with you using?

**Note: racial relations and language in the US continue to evolve, and what is proper today might be offensive tomorrow.*

Comment: Can you hint what is an example of these circumstances?

Comment: @SF. I could not do it justice in a short post. The circumstances are an integral part of the post-slavery, post-civil rights culture of multi-racial America. It depends on the race/culture/ethnicity of the people speaking, in-group vs. out-group status, the formality of the context, the history of the situation/place/time, etc. Suffice it to say that calling a person "That Negro over there...." is more likely to be offensive, but discussing *The United Negro College Fund* in a formal context is less likely to be offensive.

Comment: Strangely enough, UNCF's web site uses the acronym exclusively. It takes digging into the annual report to get the full name of this organization.

Comment: Using "negro" (especially if pronounced NEE-grow or NIG-row) can reasonably suggest that the person using it would like to go back to the status quo that prevailed before Civil Rights Days, when Black people "knew their place", lynching was still a real possibility for any imagined transgression, and, with vanishingly-few exceptions, all the wealth and power of the nation was in White hands.  When cops can still, in the 21st c., roust, assault, and even shoot Black people dead with impunity, it should be clear why Black people are very alive to any hint that things could get even worse again.

Comment: @MMacD Using "Black" capitalised - that's probably more offensive than "Negro".

Comment: @gnasher729 It's fine as an adjective, eg. *the Black communities* (indeed, [AP style recommends capitalization](https://apnews.com/article/71386b46dbff8190e71493a763e8f45a) ), it's rather offensive as a noun (eg. *?he's a Black*).

Answer (score 12):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* has a note about using *Negro*.

> Since the Black Power movement of the 1960s, however, when the term *black* was favored as the term to express racial pride, *Negro* has dropped out of favor and now seems out of date or even offensive in both US and British English. The 2010 US Census questionnaire was criticized when it retained the racial designation *Negro* as an option (along with *Black* and *African Am.*). The Census Bureau defended its decision, citing the 2000 Census forms, on which more than 56,000 individuals handwrote "Negro" (even though it was already on the form). Apparenly, *Negro* continues to be the identity strongly preferred by some Americans.

The NOAD itself, in the definition of *Negro*, reports the word as dated, and often offensive.

About *Black*, the note the NOAD has is the following:

> *Black*, designating Americans of African heritage, became the most widely used and accepted term in the 1960s and 1970s, replacing *Negro*. It is not usually capitalized: *black Americans*. Through the 1980s, the more formal *African American* replaced *black* in much usage, but both are now generally acceptable. *Afro-American*, first recorded in the 19th century and popular in the 1960s and 1970s, is now heard mostly in anthropological and cultural contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The word "negro" is slightly offensive. I'd recommend not using it, and I'd recommend not to get too offended if you hear or read it. It is actually practically not used anymore.

Even racists don't use it - because it is nowhere near offensive enough for their purposes. They will use a different word, also containing the letters n, g, and r, which is deeply offensive and which you should *not* use unless you want to be punched in the face.

Comment: Define "slightly offensive" less offensive than saying a person is *colored*?

Comment: Do you have a source for your second paragraph? I am very interested in more details about the usage of the "ni"-word. Thank you.